# Magento 2.2.1: Attribute values sort by name

Tags: attributes, magento-2.2.1

I write here for an help.

Magento 2.2.1: For a few days I'm using Magento 2, after I used it for a couple of years Magento 1. I am aware of the presence of an important discomfort: attribute values are not sorted alphabetically, but only by order of insertion.
It's a serious problem, especially if the variables are so many. How can I fix it?

I tried to follow the other solutions in this forum, but I could not solve it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: please let me what attributes you want? product/customer ??

Comment: Product attribute: e.g., color; manufacture

Comment: Do you mean the attribute option?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Not attribute values, but attribute options (e.g., black, white ; apple, samsung, nokia).

Answer (score 0):

The fixes works in Magento 2.1.x but in 2.2.x the classes has been refactored and previous workaround stop working.

Info about the issue here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7441

Comment: I hope it will be solved with Magento upcoming updates.